# unlink a php file in Codeigniter project?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to delete a php file with unlink function in Codeigniter? it has a path:

> ./public_html/application/views/driver/tobedeleted.php

so to delete this file i created a route like

```
$route['delete']='my_controller/delete';
```

and in my controller's delete function i am executing a testdelete.php script which is inside my web directory.

```
public function delete(){
      $this->load->view('web/testdelete');
  }
```

and here is the code of testdelete.php:

```
<?php 

  unlink("./public_html/application/views/driver/tobedeleted.php");

  ?>
```

but whenever i try to do that it says:

> file not found

can anyone help me with this . Thanks in advance <3.

Comment: the file ./ is not the root of the directory it should the root path

Comment: can u tell me the root path??

Comment: use unlink(trim(FC_PATH),'/')."/application/views/driver/tobedeleted.php"); instead

Comment: no directory error

Comment: There are a few reasons but some are you can't reach it from the apache user, or your apache configuration will not let you reach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use:

```
unlink(FCPATH."/application/views/driver/tobedeleted.php");
```

FCPATH carries root path till the application folder.